# asp Textbox with ajax autocomplete does work but not really selecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

as i am using this method for auto complete it's my first time , and i did manage to "make it work" after
a few hours of research i didn't yet understand why but the behavior of the method is weird , i am getting the list of options for the auto complete though it does not 
"home" on the right possible match rather stays on the first line under the text box.

declaring

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ac" %>
```

this is the tag i am using i aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"  EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="TBX_theMonthInsert" runat="server" Width="60" />
```

the ajax part

```
<ac:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" EnableCaching="true" 
BehaviorID="AutoCompleteCities" TargetControlID="TBX_theMonthInsert" 
        ServiceMethod="GenerateMonthNames" MinimumPrefixLength="2"
        ContextKey="GenerateMonthNames"  CompletionSetCount="2" runat="server" 

        FirstRowSelected="true" CompletionInterval="350" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                   </ac:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Code behind

```
        [ScriptMethod()]
        [WebMethod]
        public static string[] GenerateMonthNames(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
        {
            List<string> items = new List<string>();
            items.Add("Oliver");
            items.Add("Olsen");
            items.Add("learns");
            items.Add("how");
            items.Add("change");
            items.Add("world");
            items.Add("engaging");


            return items.ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with searching /query within the `GenerateMonthNames`
for the `prefixText` parameter

```
    public static List<string> GenerateMonthNames(string prefixText)
    {
      List<string> items = new List<string>();
         items.Add("Oliver");
         items.Add("Olsen");
         items.Add("learns");
         items.Add("how");
         items.Add("change");
         items.Add("world");
         items.Add("engaging");  

         var returnList = items.Where(item=>item.Contains(prefixTest)).ToList();
         returnList.Sort();
         return returnList; 
     }
```

this is what i was missing in the autoComplete - Code behind section .

when you are typing inside the target TextBox , you're  activating the "on text changed" trigger for the ajax auto complete function to execute.

it is the textBox text Changed Event that triggers Ajax - code behind auto complete "command"

then it sends the prefixText as a parameter with each key stroke inside the targeted TextBox,

the code behind method(in this example "GenerateMonthNames")  is searching partial text(prefixText parameter) within each element of the list, then filters out (that is the part i was missing e.g. "it wasn't working") the elements that do not contain text you've entered in target TextBox .
I hope it will clarify some other people that are also new to using ajax autoComplete
facing the same problem.